# SQL Logic Help for Outer Joins with Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where we have member data in table 'MEMBERS'. Then for each type of task assigned to a member, they are stored in 4 separate tables, PRSP_TASKS, PRSP_CALLS, PRSP_TOURS, and PRSP_EMAILS. Those four tables are linked back to the members table with a foreign key of memid = prospectid.

What I am attempting to do, is for each entry in the members table that was entered between two dates, to return all rows from each of the four tables. If there aren't any rows, then I still need to have one row signifying that.

I do not seem to be getting the records that are in the MEMBERS table but that have no rows in the other four tables.

```
SELECT MEMBERS.memid,
       MEMBERS.fname,
       MEMBERS.lname,
       MEMBERS.relationship,
       MEMBERS.employeeid,
       MEMBERS.entrydate,
       PRSP_TOURS.tourdate,
       PRSP_TOURS.tournote,
       PRSP_CALLS.calldate,
       PRSP_CALLS.callnote,
       PRSP_EMAILS.emaildate,
       PRSP_EMAILS.emailsubject,
       PRSP_TASKS.taskdate,
       PRSP_TASKS.tasknote
FROM   MEMBERS
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PRSP_TASKS
                    ON MEMBERS.memid = PRSP_TASKS.memid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PRSP_TOURS
                    ON MEMBERS.memid = PRSP_TOURS.prospectid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PRSP_CALLS
                    ON MEMBERS.memid = PRSP_CALLS.prospectid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PRSP_EMAILS
                    ON MEMBERS.memid = PRSP_EMAILS.prospectid
WHERE  ( MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite )
       AND ( MEMBERS.relationship = 'P' )
       AND ( MEMBERS.entrydate BETWEEN @rvEntryDateStart AND @rvEntryDateEnd )
```

Comment: Your query should return any members matching your `where` criteria. Are you sure the missing records don't match your criteria?

Comment: Show some data that you'd expect to see that are not.  be sure to include sideID, relationship, and entry date and the  values passed into your variables.  If you comment out all the PRSP_ values in the select and the left joins you still don't get those records right?

Comment: UPDATE: Ok, you are correct. I left out am important detail. The above query does everything that it is supposed to. But If I add an additional level and ask for only entries in those 4 tables after a certain date, I do not receive the null for those tables for the entry in MEMBERS. SORRY for the confusion. My requirements changes from when I was working on this.

Comment: @Merlin -- Don't put that criteria in the `where` clause, but instead, put it in the `on` clauses.  If you put it in the `where` clause, you'll negate the `outer joins` as you're noticing.